# Difference conceptual schema and logical view

Tags: database, database-schema

Whats the difference between a database's conceptual schema and its logical view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Conceptual` - a model that captured the essential data that needed to be stored and the relationships between elements

`Logical view` constists of the name of the table, the attributes it contains, their types, the constraints on the attributes, if any.

Check this out:- http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~casanova/Publications/Papers/2007-Papers/2007-Computer.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Logical schema is the end user view of the database represented by tables

Conceptual schema represents data as viewed by the computer e.g sql commands

Answer (score 0):

**Logical level**- is the user view of the database which is independent of the dbms implementation 
**conceptual level**-is the representation of the entities and their attributes which is independent of the s/w or h/w implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptual schema represents information on an implementation-independent level, often using graphical notations

Logical schema represents information according to data model of implementation language or system